# PLN - Ideias de como identificar sujeito e predicado

Tags: string

Comecei a trabalhar em um projeto no meu tempo livre. No momento preciso saber como identificar o sujeito em uma frase, naturalmente uma frase em português br é composta de sujeito + predicado, estou supondo que todas as frases venham nesse formato e achei 3 meios de identificar, através dos **pronomes** ou **artigo + substantivo** ou através do **verbo** (o sujeito muitas vezes vem antes do verbo). A pergunta é, *existe algum jeito mais simples de identificar o sujeito?*

Comment: Eu trabalhei brevemente com esse assunto, mas pouco me lembro. Eu sei que o Tiago Cunha era muito bom (na época que o conheci, doutorando em letras pela UFC - Universidade Federal do Ceará). Ele me ensinou muito sobre o assunto. Vou procurar aqui algo dele para compartilhar contigo.

Comment: Obrigado! Vai ser de grande ajuda, aguardo resposta.

Comment: Tenho aqui alguns links úteis: http://bdtd.ibict.br/vufind/Record/UFES_3218fdcf91c4a52a2cc1ed03496f0328 http://www.repositorio.ufc.br/bitstream/riufc/8226/1/2013_tese_tmcunha.pdf http://www.mdcc.ufc.br/teses/doc_download/237-

Comment: Gotcha! Vou dar uma lida em todos os 3, tenho certeza que irão me ajudar, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Quando tiver descoberto, publica a resposta aqui? Foi mal  não ter algo mais direto, só essas acadêmicas

Comment: Publico sim, desculpe a demora para responder.